# gedmo doctrine translatable extension. Retrieve all translations or a specific one (different from the current locale)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, locale, doctrine-extensions

I've an entity that uses gedmo doctrine translatable extension.
I'm able to load this entity in the current locale.

Now, for an admin panel where I want users to see and edit the various translations, I want to show all the translations or a specific one chosen by the user.

I just have the ->getTranslations method on that entity. There's another trick to load just the select translation?
Is there any best practice for the given scenario?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this retrieving the translations from the entity "Translation Repository" and passing to the Form Model (a model i created to handle the translations):

```
$nodeRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeCoreBundle:Node');
$node = $repository->find($id);

$translationsRepository = $this->getDoctrine()>getRepository('Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\NodeTranslation');

// retrieving the translations for the given node
$translations = $repository->findTranslations($node);

$model = new TranslatableModel($node, $translations, ...);
```

I hope this would help someone...

Ciao